# django: No Techpost matches the given query

Tags: python, django

I'm new Django and have been working on project. When I click on my techposts. it says `No Techpost matches the given query`. It was working fine and I didn't change anything. Not sure what could have happened. It has happened 2-3 times. Database flush used to fix this issue. But now nothing is working. Please suggest how do I fix this and the possible reason behind this?

PS: Found similar questions but their answers didnt help.

CODE:

models.py

```
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(status='published')


class Techpost(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICS=(
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published')
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='tech_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices = STATUS_CHOICS, default='draft')
    tags = TaggableManager()


class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


objects = models.Manager() # default manager
published = PublishedManager() # Custom Manager.


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('rincon:techpost_details', args=[
        self.publish.year,
        self.publish.strftime('%m'),
        self.publish.strftime('%d'),
        self.slug
    ])


class Comment(models.Model):
    techpost = models.ForeignKey(Techpost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='comments')
    comment     = models.TextField()
    created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True)
    active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)

def __str__(self):
    return "Comment on {}".format(self.techpost)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def techpost_details(request, year, month, day, techpost):

techpost = get_object_or_404(Techpost, slug=techpost, status='published',
                             publish__year=year, publish__month=month, publish__day=day)
comments = techpost.comments.filter(active=True)
if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.techpost = techpost
        new_comment.save()
        comment_form = CommentForm()
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()

techpost_tags_ids = techpost.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
similar_techposts = Techpost.published.filter(tags__in=techpost_tags_ids)\
    .exclude(id=techpost.id)
similar_techposts = similar_techposts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
    .order_by('-same_tags', '-publish')[:4]
return render(request, 'rincon/details.html', {'techpost': techpost, 'comments': comments, 'comment_form': comment_form, 'similar_techposts': similar_techposts})
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'rincon'
urlpatterns =[
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('submit/', views.request_submit, name='request_submit'),
path('techposts/', views.techpost_list, name='techpost_list'),
path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.techpost_list, name='techpost_list_by_tag'),
path('<slug:techpost_id>/share/', views.techpost_share, name='techpost_share'),
path('search/', views.techpost_search, name='techpost_search'),
path('hotfixes/', views.hotfixes, name='hotfixes'),
path('autocomplete/', views.autocomplete, name='autocomplete'),
path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:techpost>/', views.techpost_details, name='techpost_details'),
```

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  https://localhost/rincon/2018/05/28/test/
Raised by:  rincon.views.techpost_details

No Techpost matches the given query.
 here is the traceback from webpage:
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page

Comment: You're seing this page because of `get_object_or_404`, there's no records with the arguments passed in your db. `get_object_or_404` means if the object exists, you get it, otherwise a 404 page appears

Comment: I get the object with API call (shell) from database but when I try to fetch it from webpage it give me 404. not sure why.
Also, i tried creating new posts and I m getting the same error for those as well.

Comment: cannot add it, says syntax error. my view is available above. please show how to do it?

Comment: I missed a comma, try this `print("year",year, "month",month, "day",day, "techpost",techpost)`

Comment: nothing has changed. error remains same

Comment: The reason I asked you to do that, it's because I want to make sure that Django retrieve all the arguments there `def techpost_details(request, year, month, day, techpost):` from your url pattern

Comment: shell output:
>>> Techpost.published.filter(publish__year=2018)
<QuerySet [<Techpost: test>]> but month and day giving empty queryset

Comment: `def techpost_details(request, year, month, day, techpost):`
       `print("year",year, "month",month, "day",day, "techpost",techpost)` add it right after, and show the output

Comment: still same! here is the another output from shell to know that year, month m date is working.
>>> Techpost.objects.get(pk=1).get_absolute_url()
'/rincon/2018/05/28/test/'

Comment: his status is `published` or `draft`?

Comment: Found Solution: it was very simple.
in settings.py changed USE_TZ = True to USE_TZ = False
Do you know why it's relatedto time zone?